# Does shaking off a Husk count as a melee kill?

Tags: mass-effect-3, achievements

The *Striker/Bruiser* accomplishments/achievements/tropies require you to "Kill 25/100 enemies with melee attacks" respectively. Seeing as I'm the "shoot enemies from far away as possible" type of player, I rarely get up close and personal, however, Husks that latch on to you can be killed by a melee counter.

I wonder - does killing off a Husk latching on to you with the melee button count as a melee kill or do I have to actually kill enemies with the melee button?

Comment: In multiplayer you do not get points for shaking them off but you do for killing them with melee attack so it is two different things, but I do not know if it still counts towards the achievement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You do kill them with melee after all.

Comment: do you have any proof of this ? Or is it just some guessing ?

Comment: I can confirm that shacking off a husk is a melee kill

Answer (score 1):

It will count as a melee kill.